# Syntax error in SQL create table

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I am trying to get more familiat with SQL and I am using MySql to test my SQL queries.I seem to be getting a sintax error in this statement:

```
CREATE TABLE dog
(
  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  name varchar(255),
  descr text,
  size enum('small','medium','large'),
  date timestamp(14),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**Error:**

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(14), PRIMARY KEY (id) )ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 7

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Remove `(11)` from your query just use `id int NOT NULL auto_increment,`

Comment: Change: timestamp(14) -> timestamp

Comment: I hope it should be an warning in statement it not an error:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try mentioning like this

```
CREATE TABLE dog

(
  id int NOT NULL auto_increment,
  name varchar(255),
  descr text,
  size enum('small','medium','large'),
  date timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 2):

'`TIMESTAMP(14)`' is deprecated; use '`TIMESTAMP`' instead

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
CREATE TABLE dog

(
  id int NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(255),
  descr text,
  size enum('small','medium','large'),
  date timestamp
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

PRIMARY KEY statement has to be precised with the field declaration