# Incorrect syntax with VARCHAR(MAX) when creating table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating an SQL table using PHP but I'm getting an error and I don't know why. This is the code

```
CREATE TABLE posts
(
    P_Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Title VARCHAR(200),
    Post VARCHAR(MAX),
    PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
)
```

The error that I'm getting is

> Error creating table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MAX), PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)' at line 5

Comment: I think you need to specify a value there (eg. VARCHAR(255)).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error in SQL create table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951921/syntax-error-in-sql-create-table)

Comment: @AlexJimenez: Mr. Jimenez, if any of these answers helped you, please see to it that you accept the one that solved your issue. Thank you.

Comment: `Varchar(MAX)` is a SQL Server specific extension.  You'll have to put a number in there...

Answer (score 2):

VARCHAR(MAX) is not supported in MySql, I think you need to specify a figure in there. I think 64k is the max.

```
VARCHAR(65535)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE posts
(_Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Title VARCHAR(200),
Post VARCHAR(MAX),
PRIMARY KEY (P_Id))
```

What is MAX? Got too many commas! Why are you using PHP to initialize a database?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you can't use (MAX) for VARCHAR in mySQL.

See:

- [Equivalent of varchar(max) in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332798/equivalent-of-varcharmax-in-mysql)
- [What is the maximum range of varchar in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907467/what-is-the-maximum-range-of-varchar-in-mysql)

I think you want:

```
...
Post VARCHAR(65535),
...
```